# C++ Trying to output a second dimension vector using std::cout

Tags: c++

I'm working towards a function to do matrix multiplication and I want to output the modified vector into the console so I know what it's doing. Right now I'm getting some weird errors that I don't understand (coming from python).

Errors:

```
Warning C26444  Avoid unnamed objects with custom construction and destruction (es.84). (ln 63)

Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\Users\thewo\Desktop\SFML\SFML Projects\Matrix Multiplication\Release\Matrix Multiplication.exe'    Matrix Multiplication   C:\Users\thewo\Desktop\SFML\SFML Projects\Matrix Multiplication\LINK    1       

Error   MSB6006 "link.exe" exited with code 1104.   Matrix Multiplication   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 810
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>

std::list<int> v2DS(std::vector< std::vector<int> > vect2d) {
    std::list<int> vS;
    int vD1 = vect2d.size();
    int vD2 = vect2d[0].size();
    vS.push_back(vD1);
    vS.push_back(vD2);
    std::cout << "dims: " << vD1 << " : " << vD2 << std::endl;

    return vS;
}

std::vector< std::vector<int> > Matrix_Multiplication(std::vector< std::vector<int> > v1, std::vector< std::vector<int> > v2) {
    // Error Detection for debug
    if (v1.size()==0) {
        std::cout << "Error:\tVector 1 is empty" << std::endl;
    }
    if (v2.size() == 0) {
        std::cout << "Error:\tVector 2 is empty" << std::endl;
    }
    // v1 is the default, v2 gets rotated and multiplied
    if (v1.size() == v2[0].size()) {
        std::vector< std::vector<int> > vTEMP;
        std::vector< std::vector<int> >::iterator x;// Predefining iterators cuz c++
        std::vector<int>::iterator y;
        int xTemp, yTemp;
        for (x = v2.begin(); x != v2.end(); ++x) {
            xTemp = std::distance(v2.begin(), x);
            for (y = x->begin(); y != x->end(); ++y) {
                yTemp = std::distance(x->begin(), y);
                vTEMP[xTemp].push_back(v2[yTemp][xTemp]);
            }
            std::ostream_iterator<int> vPrint(std::cout, ", ");
            std::copy(vTEMP[xTemp].begin(), vTEMP[xTemp].end(), vPrint);
        }
        return vTEMP;
    }
    // Size Error Handling
    else {
        std::cout << "\t Unable to start mMultiplication, check vector dimension sizes." << std::endl;
    }

}


int main() {
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > v1{
        {1,2},
        {3,4}   
    };

    std::vector< std::vector<int> > v2{
        {1,2},
        {3,4}
    };

    Matrix_Multiplication(v1,v2);

    return 0;
}
```

The current matrix multiplication function is basically just trying to rotate an array like this from python:

```
arr = [[],[],[],[],[]]
arr2 = [[],[],[],[]]
c = 0
for x in range(0,5):
    for i in range(0,4):
        arr[x].append(c)
        c+=1
    print(arr[x])

for x in range(0,len(arr[0])):
    for y in range(0,len(arr)):
        arr2[x].append(arr[y][x])
arr2.reverse()
for x in range(0,len(arr[0])):
    print(arr2[x])
```

Thanks a head of time.

Comment: Unrelated: Make it `#include <cmath>` instead of `#include <math.h>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line in your inner loop:

```cpp
vTEMP[xTemp].push_back(v2[yTemp][xTemp]);
```

is attempting to `push_back` an `int` value into the vector `vTemp[xTemp]` - but this vector doesn't exist (`vTEMP` exists but is *empty*, so any `vTemp[i]` is meaningless/non-existent), so you have **undefined behaviour**.

To make it work, you should `resize` the 2D vector `vTEMP` so that it has the required number of (1D) 'sub-vectors' before you run the loops, such as like this:

```cpp
    if (v1.size() == v2[0].size()) {
        std::vector< std::vector<int> > vTEMP;
        vTEMP.resize(v2[0].size()); // Here, we allocate the array of "sub-vectors"
        //... and continue with your code!
```

Also note that your `Matrix_Multiplication` function has an invalid return in the case of errors! Possibly, you could have something along these lines:

```cpp
    // Size Error Handling
    else {
        std::cout << "\t Unable to start mMultiplication, check vector dimension sizes." << std::endl;
        std::vector< std::vector<int> > vDUMMY;
        return vDUMMY;
    }
```

In your build, the "LNK1104" error is probably happening because the target .exe file from a previous build is still running: Did you actually check that the program exits?

The line `vTEMP[xTemp].push_back(v2[yTemp][xTemp]);` is causing ***undefined behaviour*** (described above), which *could* make the program hang.

Comment: `vTEMP.reserve` will increase the **capacity** of the vector, but the **size** does not change, so it will still be invalid. `Here, we allocate the array of "sub-vectors"`  Only the memory that is required to hold that element is reserved.

Comment: @t.niese OK, noted! I should have used `resize` rather than `reserve` (now edited, thanks to your helpful critique).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, at first it didn't work so I restarted my computer because I think something was running in the background that shouldn't have. However, I still get some weirdness with debug on VS which pops up xmemory ln 1038 as a read access violation "_First was 0x20" and I have no idea what it means.

Comment: Oh, fixed it. I was still calling an undefined value when the function was called because vDummy is only returned when the other conditions are untrue.